# The "activities" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Per [a discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/conversation/conversation-that-spawned-the-activities-tag) in our chat room, I've created the "[activities](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags/activities/info)" tag to mark questions that fall in a particular grey area: questions that aren't about parenting per se, but are about activities we participate in with our children, or support our children participating in.

The goal is that we can err on the side of including such questions even if they are borderline, as long as they are consistently tagged so that those not interested in such discussion can effortlessly ignore them.

Is the include-but-tag option a good compromise?

Do you feel another approach would be better?

Comment: I'd like to understand better what the tag is for, because to me "activities" is extremely general. Would a different tag word be more accurate? Something in the spirit of "activities-that-are-not-parenting-related" but worded better?

Comment: @torbengb: If you can come up with a better name, I'll be in favor of changing it.  We just couldn't think of one.

Comment: I'm trying and also coming up pretty blank. Should we try to discuss this [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/806918#806918)?